# while loop condition evaluation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

Normally, I'd expect this while loop condition to evaluate to true and the code inside would get run:

```
while ([" ", ":", ",", ""].includes("")) {
        cursor = getCh();
      }
```

If you copy the snippet below into devtools, you will see that on line 18 the same scenario as I outlined above evaluates to false and the code inside doesn't run. I'm trying to find out why. Again, if you place a breakpoint on line 18 and step into the nextValue function, you will see that cursor gets set to an empty string, and then the while loop's conditional gets checked. Instead of evaluating to true and entering the loop, it evaluates to false as I outlined above. **The rest of the parseJSON function is not part of the question I'm trying to answer, I just want to know why the while loop inside the nextValue helper function doesn't get entered when the cursor variable is equal to an empty string.** It was necessary to paste all the code since it's the only time I've experienced the problem.

I've used dev tools to inspect the values as the function runs and everything looks as it should.

```js
var parseJSON = function(json) {


  json = json.split("")
  var cursor = json[0];

  function parser() {


    var grammar = {


      'object': {
        'build': function() {
          var obj = {};

          while (cursor != "}") {
            nextValue([" ", ":", ",", '']);
            if (cursor === undefined || cursor === "}") {
              cursor = getCh();
              return obj;
            }
            var property = parser(json);
            nextValue([":", " "]);
            obj[property] = parser(json);
          }

          cursor = getCh();
          return obj;
        },
        'identifier': ["{", ":", "}"]
      }

    };

    // Resets json variable and returns the first character
    function getCh() {
      json = json.slice(1);
      return json[0];
    }

    // Resets cursor until cursor does not equal argument
    function nextValue(char) {
      // run getCh() while not a value
      cursor = getCh();
      while (char.includes(cursor)) {
        cursor = getCh();
      }
    }

    // Searches through type identifiers in our grammar to determine 
    // whichfunction to run
    for (var key in grammar) {
      if (grammar[key].identifier.includes(cursor)) {
        return grammar[key].build();
      }
    }
  };

  return parser(json);
};
var input = '{\r\n' +
  '          "glossary": {\n' +
  '              "title": "example glossary",\n\r' +
  '      \t\t"GlossDiv": {\r\n' +
  '                  "title": "S",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t"GlossList": {\r\n' +
  '                      "GlossEntry": {\r\n' +
  '                          "ID": "SGML",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t"SortAs": "SGML",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t"GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized ' +
  'Markup Language",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t"Acronym": "SGML",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t"Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t"GlossDef": {\r\n' +
  '                              "para": "A meta-markup language,' +
  ' used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t\t"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]\r\n' +
  '                          },\r\n' +
  '      \t\t\t\t\t"GlossSee": "markup"\r\n' +
  '                      }\r\n' +
  '                  }\r\n' +
  '              }\r\n' +
  '          }\r\n' +
  '      }\r\n'
console.log(parseJSON(input));
```

Comment: I am not sure how `getCh()` in your code can return an empty string. It seems it can only return a string or `undefined`.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt getCh() returns whatever is at the front of the json array at index 0, but that's not the problem I'm having. If you place a breakpoint on line 18 and step into the nextValue function, you will see that cursor gets set to an empty string, and then the while loop's conditional gets checked. Instead of evaluating to true and entering the loop, it evaluates to false as I outlined above.

Comment: It only looks like empty string, If you run in the console `cursor.charCodeAt(0)` after `cursor` is set, you will get `13` (i.e. `'\r'`) and `cursor.length` is `1`. You cannot get an empty string from `str[index]`, only a 1 character substring or `undefined` if the `index` is out of bound.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Thanks, that makes sense and solves the mystery.